# Weierstrass theorem? Norm unclear...

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I found a theorem as follows:

Let $a<b$, $f\in C([a,b])$ and $\epsilon >0$. Then there exists a polynomial $p$ such that

$\vert \vert f-p \vert \vert_{C_b ([a,b])} < \epsilon$.

Is this a classical Weierstrass theorem? And can anyone explain me the norm used above ($\vert \vert \cdot \vert \vert_{C_b ([a,b])}$). Is this a supremum norm?

Thank you!

Comment: Yes, typically when one write $C[a,b]$ or $C([a,b])$ in this context, it means the continuous functions with the $\sup$ ($\max$) norm. This is the Stone Weierstrass (or Bishop's) theorem.

Comment: Thanks! Is it somewhat possible to show that the Legendre polynomials are an orthonormal basis on $L^2 ([-1,1])$ with the help of the theorem above?

Comment: That's a different question, but I'm not sure how polynomial approximation would help when you are dealing with polynomials in the first place.

Comment: perhaps with some denseness argument?...

Comment: I'm sorry, I see what you are asking now. Well, you could show that the polynomials are dense in the continuous functions (as a subset of $L^2$), but you still need to show that the continuous functions are dense in $L^2$. (Some authors define $L^2$ as the completion of the continuous functions with respect to the $L^2$ norm.)

Comment: but where come the legendre polynomials into play?

Comment: This is really a different question. The Legendre polynomials arise from applying Gram Schmidt to the polynomials $x \mapsto x^k$, so using them to show that they form a Schauder basis is no different than using the polynomials $x \mapsto x^k$ directly.